# Top 10 players with the highest batting average

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: 1]

Batting average = total number of runs scored / number of times out.

Here we need to make sure to include run outs (on non-striker end)

Output like :

```
Batsman_name     Average

KL Rahul            44
```

Error:

> Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`batsman_runs`' given input columns: [_*auto_generated_subquery_name.Batsman*]; line 1 pos 21;
> 'Sort ['Average DESC NULLS LAST], true

```
select Batsman_, sum(batsman_runs)/count(player_dismissed) as Average 
from
(
 (select batsman as Batsman_ from IPL_BALL_BY_BALL) 
 union all 
 (select non_striker as Batsman_ from IPL_BALL_BY_BALL)
)
group by Batsman_ 
order by Average desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

because from your subquery ( result of union) you only returning "Batsman_" column. you have to retunr all the column you need :

```
select Batsman_, sum(batsman_runs)/count(player_dismissed) as Average 
from
(
 (select batsman as Batsman_,batsman_runs,player_dismissed from IPL_BALL_BY_BALL) 
 union all 
 (select non_striker as Batsman_,batsman_runs,player_dismissed from IPL_BALL_BY_BALL)
)
group by Batsman_ 
order by Average desc;
```

Comment: i am not getting average correctly we need to make sure to include run outs (on non-striker end)

Comment: you are asking a new question , I recommend you post a new question with sample data and desired output

Comment: data is present in the image that i have attached and desired output also i have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Batsman_, sum(batsman_runs)/count(player_dismissed) as Average from
((select batsman as Batsman_,batsman_runs,player_dismissed from IPL_BALL_BY_BALL) union all (select non_striker as Batsman_,batsman_runs,player_dismissed
from IPL_BALL_BY_BALL))
group by Batsman_ order by Average desc;
```

You forgot fields "batsman_run & player_dismissed" in your inner sql

Comment: i think their is something problem in login average is not according to run out on non strike end can you help me out

Comment: Probably, but it's another question, so first close this one, test what you want and ask a new question you have other pb.

Comment: The code i tried i thought it would give me the correct output after removing error but it is not giving the correct output. I have already attached an image with sample data