# list of top 10 players with the highest batting average

Tags: mysql, sql

Batting average = total number of runs scored/number of times they have been out

Make sure to include run outs (on non-striker end) as valid out while calculating average.

Here is the Sample data ---
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4jmH.png)

```
select Batsman_, sum(case when is_wicket=1 and (dismissal_kind='run out' 
and player_dismissed 
= non_striker) then 1 else 0 end) as Average from
((select batsman as 
Batsman_,is_wicket,dismissal_kind,player_dismissed,non_striker from 
IPL_BALL_BY_BALL) union all (select non_striker as 
Batsman_,is_wicket,dismissal_kind,player_dismissed,non_striker from 
IPL_BALL_BY_BALL))
group by Batsman_ order by Average desc limit 10;
```

OUTPUT--

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ehmjz.png)

Expacted output--

Batsman_    Average

MS Dhoni    40

KD Kharthik   26

Comment: Comment as before

Comment: Note the following, which appears on [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): ___DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.___ _- copy or type the text into the question_

Comment: try to provide more information and structure it a bit better, so that it can be read easily:
1. how does the full table look, on which you're selecting the data?
2. what is your exact goal? SELECT TOP 10 ... ?

Comment: I have added the sample data image and ouput image

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Top 10 players with the highest batting average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67827721/top-10-players-with-the-highest-batting-average)

Comment: NO, I am trying to solve this question with different ways but not getting the correct output. very complex question this is

Answer (score -1):

Finally i got the answer

```
select batsman,sum(batsman_runs)/sum(case when is_wicket=1 and 
(player_dismissed 
= non_striker or player_dismissed = batsman) then 1 else 0 end) as 
average from 
IPL_BALL_BY_BALL group by batsman order by average desc limit 10;
```